# HackerRank: Climbing the Leaderboard

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, statistics, binary-search

Below is my solution to [Climbing the Leaderboard on HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/climbing-the-leaderboard):

> Alice is playing an arcade game and wants to climb to the top of the
>   leaderboard. Can you help her track her ranking as she beats each
>   level? The game uses Dense Ranking, so its leaderboard works like
>   this:
>
> - The player with the highest score is ranked number 1 on the
>     leaderboard.
> - Players who have equal scores receive the same ranking
>     number, and the next player(s) receive the immediately following
>     ranking number.
>
> For example, four players have the scores 100, 90, 90, and 80.
>   Those players will have ranks 1, 2, 2, and 3, respectively.
>
> When Alice starts playing, there are already \$n\$ people on the
>   leaderboard. The score of each player \$i\$ is denoted by \$s_i\$. Alice plays for \$m\$
>   levels, and we denote her total score after passing each level \$j\$ as \$alice_j\$.
>   After completing each level, Alice wants to know her current rank.
>
> You are given an array, \$scores\$, of *monotonically decreasing* leaderboard
>   scores, and another array, \$alice\$, of Alice's cumulative scores for each
>   level of the game. You must print \$m\$ integers. The \$j^{th}\$ integer should
>   indicate the current rank of alice after passing the \$j^{th}\$ level.

For example, when \$scores\$ is:

```
100 100 50 40 40 20 10
```

And \$alice\$ is:

```
5 25 50 120
```

The rankings for each score of Alice are 6, 4, 2, 1.

My code below works for most test cases,
except the last few where it times out.

```
function dedupe(arr, n) {
  const result = [];

  for(let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if(!result.includes(arr[i])) {
      result.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

const cache = {};

function binarySearchRankings(input, keySearch, min, max) {
  if(keySearch > input[0]) {
    return 1;
  }

  if(cache[keySearch]) {
    return cache[keySearch];
  }

  let mid = 0;

  while(min <= max) {

    mid = Math.ceil((min + max) / 2);

    if(keySearch === input[mid]) {
      const result = ++mid;
      cache[keySearch] = result;
      return result;
    } else if(keySearch >= input[mid]) {
      max = mid - 1;
    } else {
      min = mid + 1;
    }
  }

  if(keySearch <= input[mid]) {
    cache[keySearch] = mid + 2;
    return mid + 2;
  }

  if(keySearch > input[mid]) {
    cache[keySearch] = mid + 1;
    return mid + 1;
  }

  return mid;
}

const deduped = dedupe(scores, n);

for(var i = 0; i < m; i++) {
  const a = binarySearchRankings(deduped, alice[i], 0, deduped.length -1);

  console.log(a);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Performance

It's the `dedupe` implementation that drags the performance of your solution down.
It's because `Array.prototype.includes()` does a linear search,
so your implementation becomes \$O(n^2)\$.
If you rewrite this function to be \$O(n)\$,
the solution will pass all tests.

#### Using arrays

The `dedupe` function takes as parameters an array and its size.
The size parameter is unnecessary and potentially confusing,
because you can always access that with `.length`.

#### Binary search

A common practice when implementing binary search over a list is to return the index of a value if it is found,
otherwise return a negative value from which the insertion point can be computed using the formula `-1 -ret`.
It would be cleaner to implement `binarySearch(arr, value, low, high)` in 
a way to follow this common contract,
and another `rank` function that would use the result of `binarySearch` to compute the correct rank.

Also, the implementation is a bit complicated.
Simpler techniques exist, and the cache is not needed either.
Consider this, for example:

```
function binarySearch(arr, value, lowIndex, highIndex) {
    if (lowIndex > highIndex) {
        return -(lowIndex + 1);
    }

    let midIndex = lowIndex + Math.trunc((highIndex - lowIndex) / 2);
    if (value == arr[midIndex]) {
        return midIndex;
    }
    if (value > arr[midIndex]) {
        return binarySearch(arr, value, lowIndex, midIndex - 1);
    }
    return binarySearch(arr, value, midIndex + 1, highIndex);
}
```

Comment: Changing  from Array.prototype.includes to a pretty simple check made the tests pass .  I am very surprised by this :)